# IBM Case Manager Java API Class not found

Tags: java, filenet-p8, ibm-case-manager

I'd like to develop a Java application for IBM Case Manager,
In the Case Manager info center :
-Developing case management applications
 -Java application development
  -Configuring your environment to use Java API

It says that Jars are located at : 
installation_directory/IBM/CaseManagement/CaseAPI/lib

Unfortunatly, i don't have installation_directory/IBM/CaseManagement/CaseAPI/lib
but only installation_directory/IBM/CaseManagement/lib

It only contains "displayVersion.jar" and "preconditionChecker.jar"
and no com.ibm.casemgmt.api inside.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with your CM installation, but you can get required libraries from CM deployment in WAS. The path would be something like `WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/<cell>/CaseManager.ear/CaseManager.war/WEB-INF/lib`

Please also make sure you use instructions for the same CM version that you have.

Comment: Hum ... it seems that some class are not in the acmapi.jar .... 
I was trying the "Example IBM Case Manager Java API Context", and eclipse generate an error saying that he doesn't found the class .... and indeed, i can't find the class com.ibm.casemgmt.api.context.BaseP8ConnectionCache that is supposed to be use for the constructor SimpleP8ConnectionCache();

Comment: @user2702566 The class is present in acmapi.jar - at least in the version I am looking at: Implementation-Title: Case Management API, Specification-Version: 5.1.1.0, Implementation-Version: icmapi5.1.1.001.015

Comment: Thank you for you help fnt !
Here is what i have from the version.txt in the ibm/CaseManagement folder :
IBM Case Manager, build icmproduct5.0.1.000.001.002
Includes Case Manager Builder components from build icmbuilder5.0.1.000.534
Includes Case Manager Client components from build icmclient5.0.1.000.001.001
Includes Case Manager API components from build icmapi5.0.1.000.507
Includes Case Manager Administration Client component from build icmadmin5.0.1.000.582
Includes CMIS components from build p8cmis100.002.043

Comment: Includes Content Engine components from build dap501.153d
Included Deployment Manager components from build dep452.068
Includes Process Engine API components from build pui460.002.032
Includes Process Engine REST components from build pui460.002.032

Comment: So you have CM 5.0. I don't know if class BaseP8ConnectionCache was present in that version. Could it be that you try to use instructions/code samples for version 5.1 while having version 5.0?